# Subscription queries in a multi-node environment

Tags: event-sourcing, axon

Our axon backed service runs on several nodes. Our event processors are tracking (1 segment, thus active on one node). If I subscribe to a query on node A and the event that should trigger the update is handled on node B, node A will miss this.

Is this by design or should this work and am I misconfiguring the application?

In case of the former, what could we do to implement a likewise functionality in the most axon idiomatic manner? 
(currently we poll the data source / projection directly for x seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryBus` you are using is a `SimpleQueryBus` which stays within a single JVM, always.

If you need a distributed version of the `QueryBus`, you should turn towards using [Axon Server](https://axoniq.io/product-overview/axon-server) as the centralized means to route queries between your nodes.

Note that although you could create this yourself, people have tried to do so (as shown in [this](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/pull/1153) Pull Request on the framework) and decided against it in favor of the optimizations made in Axon Server.

So, in short, I am assuming you are currently excluding the Axon Server connector.
Thus the framework gives you the `SimpleQueryBus`, which is indeed designed to not span several nodes.
And lastly, the quickest way to achieve distributed routing of queries is to use Axon Server.

Comment: Thanks, we’ll definitely check if  axon server can help us here.

Comment: Happy to have helped! Let me (or AxonIQ) know if I can help out with this.